# how to do something to after file created with filestream and pngjs?

Tags: node.js, png

I need to do something with image that created by pngjs and fs.createWriteStream

i tried to use `on finish`, but it not work

this is a simple example from pngjs page :

```
var fs = require('fs'),
PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;


fs.createReadStream('in.png')
    .pipe(new PNG({
        filterType: 4
    }))
    .on('parsed', function() {

        for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
                var idx = (this.width * y + x) << 2;

                // invert color
                this.data[idx] = 255 - this.data[idx];
                this.data[idx+1] = 255 - this.data[idx+1];
                this.data[idx+2] = 255 - this.data[idx+2];

                // and reduce opacity
                this.data[idx+3] = this.data[idx+3] >> 1;
            }
        }

        this.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.png').on('finish', function(){
//get image and proccess it to another proccess
// it got error file not found
      });
    });
```

it got error file not found
How to solve this?

Comment: Why write the image and then read it again?

Comment: because i dont know to make stream image data in next proccess  :(

Comment: Well, instead of piping the stream into `fs.createWriteStream` just pipe it in the next process. `this.pack()` will return the processed data.